# Check to see whether a range of columns hold the same value in a single row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a legacy table with 13 columns that holds values 1-5. They have to be migrated over to a new database. However some of the columns hold the value 9 which is a dummy value for "Can't rate this" and we decided that all "can't rate this" values should be turned into 3 rather than 9.

However some of the rows contain only 9's in all 13 columns and we want to skip those entirely as they are meaningless in the grand scheme of things.

I could hardcode a long "WHERE (Q1 = 9 AND Q2 = 9 AND....) but I figure there have to be an easier solution. The columns have the names Q1, Q2...Q13.

Any help with this?

Comment: Sometimes the simple solution is the best; why waste time trying to solve a problem that's already been solved? Typing this question should have taken you longer time that to actually type up the where clause :)

Comment: Writing the q1 = 9 etc query takes shorter time than posting the question here...

Comment: Scripts that are executed for a migration typically run only once and for a well known database. Therefore, they do not need to be maintainable, scalable and super nice. My advice: write the where clause as you proposed above.

Comment: On a side note: if there were a lot of columns, or you need a solution that does the same for another table with different column names a generic solution would be to use dynamic code generation and data from the system catalog views to generate the desired statement. This could easily be done as a stored procedure

Comment: @jpw Nah this is a one time thing. The table will be deleted as soon as we have made the transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to hard-code `NOT (Q1 = 9 AND Q2 = 9 AND Q3 = 9 AND Q4 = 9 AND Q5 = 9 AND Q6 = 9 AND Q7 = 9 AND Q8 = 9 AND Q9 = 9 AND Q10 = 9 AND Q11 = 9 AND Q12 = 9 AND Q13 = 9)` which one can do in a few seconds using any spreadsheet application.

Slightly faster might be an equivalent `(Q1 < 9 OR Q2 < 9 OR Q3 < 9 OR Q4 < 9 OR Q5 < 9 OR Q6 < 9 OR Q7 < 9 OR Q8 < 9 OR Q9 < 9 OR Q10 < 9 OR Q11 < 9 OR Q12 < 9 OR Q13 < 9)` expression generated in the same spreadsheet.

With possible values limited to [1-5, 9] only, a shorter though less efficient expression can be `Q1+Q2+Q3+Q4+Q5+Q6+Q7+Q8+Q9+Q10+Q11+Q12+Q13 < 117`

Just for the record, the spreadsheet formulas used:

```wiki
    A               B                       C                   D
1   1       ="Q"&A1&" = 9 AND "     ="Q"&A1&" < 9 OR "      ="Q"&A1&"+"
2   2       ="Q"&A2&" = 9 AND "     ="Q"&A2&" < 9 OR "      ="Q"&A2&"+"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be using the `unpivot` technique

```
SELECT other_cols
FROM   yourtable
       CROSS apply(VALUES (Q1),
                          (Q2),
                          (Q3),
                           ...
                          (Q12),
                          (Q13) ) tc(Q) 
Group by other_cols
Having sum(Q) = 117
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using UNPIVOT + PIVOT (aggregate functions with OVER works since SQL Server 2012):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  some_id, 
            Q, 
            CASE WHEN SUM([Values]) OVER (PARTITION BY some_id ORDER BY some_id) < 117 AND [Values] = 9 THEN 3 ELSE [Values] END as [Values]
    FROM YourTable Y
    UNPIVOT (
        [Values] FOR Q in (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13)
    ) as unpvt
) as p
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR [Q] IN (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13)
) as pvt
```

For i.e. I got one row with `9` in `Q11, Q12, Q13`. And one with all `9`, on the output I will get

```
some_id Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13
1       1   2   3   4   5   1   2   3   4   1   3   3   3
2       9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9
```